# Adding table headings to #+RESULTS: tables

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm using org-babel to generate a result I want to export in my table. However I can't find a way to easily control the heading of the table. At the moment the best I can manage is echo'ing some CSV data in my SRC. For example:

```
#+name: size-of-tcg
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir ~/lsrc/qemu/qemu.git/ :results output table :exports results
EXCL_SPEC='-and -not -iname "kvm*" -and -not -iname "gdb*" -and -not -iname "machine.c"'
echo "arch, language, lines of code"
eval find target-i386/ -xtype f ${EXCL_SPEC} > /tmp/cloc-files
cloc --quiet --csv --list-file=/tmp/cloc-files | tail -n +3 | cut -d"," -f2,5 | sed s/^/i386,/
eval find target-sparc/ -xtype f ${EXCL_SPEC} > /tmp/cloc-files
cloc --quiet --csv --list-file=/tmp/cloc-files | tail -n +3 | cut -d"," -f2,5 | sed s/^/ppc,/
eval find target-arm/ -xtype f ${EXCL_SPEC} > /tmp/cloc-files
cloc --quiet --csv --list-file=/tmp/cloc-files | tail -n +3 | cut -d"," -f2,5 | sed s/^/arm,/
echo " , Total, "
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: TCG Code for various target-*
#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border :width 90%
#+RESULTS: size-of-tcg
| arch | language     | lines of code |
| i386 | C            |         17032 |
| i386 | C/C++ Header |          4086 |
| ppc  | C            |         10483 |
| ppc  | C/C++ Header |           834 |
| arm  | C            |         28941 |
| arm  | C/C++ Header |          1962 |
|      | Total        |         63338 |
#+TBLFM: @8$3=vsum(@2$3..@7$3)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you'd like to improve in this setup? Your solution seems reasonable at first sight.

Comment: Currently the headings aren't nicely formatted. But as the input is CSV it's hard to add the |-- line for the divider. Also I can't automatically do the totalling.

Comment: I think I might need to copy the contents from the #+RESULTS: table to a new non RESULTS table and work there. But I can't find a decent way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the cleanest solution I've come up with so far is to copy the data:

```
#+name: size-of-tcg
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir ~/lsrc/qemu/qemu.git/ :results output table :exports none
EXCL_SPEC='-and -not -iname "kvm*" -and -not -iname "gdb*" -and -not -iname "machine.c"'
eval find target-i386/ -xtype f ${EXCL_SPEC} > /tmp/cloc-files
cloc --quiet --csv --list-file=/tmp/cloc-files | tail -n +3 | cut -d"," -f2,5 | sed s/^/i386,/
eval find target-sparc/ -xtype f ${EXCL_SPEC} > /tmp/cloc-files
cloc --quiet --csv --list-file=/tmp/cloc-files | tail -n +3 | cut -d"," -f2,5 | sed s/^/ppc,/
eval find target-arm/ -xtype f ${EXCL_SPEC} > /tmp/cloc-files
cloc --quiet --csv --list-file=/tmp/cloc-files | tail -n +3 | cut -d"," -f2,5 | sed s/^/arm,/
#+END_SRC
#+NAME: tcg-raw-data
#+RESULTS: size-of-tcg
| i386 | C            | 17032 |
| i386 | C/C++ Header |  4086 |
| ppc  | C            | 10483 |
| ppc  | C/C++ Header |   834 |
| arm  | C            | 28941 |
| arm  | C/C++ Header |  1962 |

#+CAPTION: TCG Code for various target-*
#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border :width 90%
| Architecture | Lines of Code |
|--------------+---------------|
| i386         |         21118 |
| ppc          |         11317 |
| arm          |         30903 |
|--------------+---------------|
| Total        |         63338 |
#+TBLFM: @2$1=remote(tcg-raw-data,@1$1)::@2$2=vsum(remote(tcg-raw-data,@1$3..@2$3))::@3$1=remote(tcg-raw-data,@3$1)::@3$2=vsum(remote(tcg-raw-data,@3$3..@4$3))::@4$1=remote(tcg-raw-data,@5$1)::@4$2=vsum(remote(tcg-raw-data,@5$3..@6$3))::@5$2=vsum(@2..@4)
```